# Access multidimensional stdClass array dynamically- Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am wondering how can i access following array using nested foreach loop ?

```
   Array ( [0] => 
   Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 3 [permID] => 2 ) 
           [1] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 3 [permID] => 3 ) 
           [2] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 2 [permID] => 4 )
           [3] => stdClass Object ( [roleID] => 2 [permID] => 5 ) )
```

here is my code:

```
    foreach($allPermissions as $allPermission) :
  
     foreach($rolePermissions as $rolePermission) :  
                 
         if($allPermission->ID==$rolePermission[0]->permID) {  ?>

          <div class="perms">
            <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" id="<?php echo $allPermission->ID; ?>"  value="<?php print $allPermission->ID; ?>"  checked><?php print $allPermission->permName; ?></option></div>
         <?php } 
        endforeach;
     endforeach;  ?>
```

This way i am able to get result relate to index 0 but unable to get result if array index goes above 0.

**Answer**

I figure out with following code:

```
             foreach($rolePermissions as $key=>$val) :  
                   foreach($val as $subkey=>$subval)
                        {
                        
                  if($allPermission->ID==$subval->permID) {
            ?>
          <div class="perms">
           <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" id="<?php echo $allPermission->ID; ?>"  value="<?php print $allPermission->ID; ?>"  checked><?php print $allPermission->permName; ?></option></div>
            <?php }  }
```

Comment: what are these tow arrays $allPermissions,$rolePermissions.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this if I understood this correctly

```
// Iterating all permissions

foreach($allPermissions as $allPermission){

// Iterating the roles of a specific permission

    foreach($allPremisson as $rolePermission) {

    }
}
```

Comment: NO: it popups following error: "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I have removed the if condition, what I meant is that now with $rolePermission you can access the stdClass Object of the inner array. As mentioned in the question you were not able to access the second element.

Comment: i want to access the each permID. But i am only able to access the permID of array index 0 because i have mentioned only 0 index. So i want to know how to make it dynamic as i can go through all indexes

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach($allPermissions as $allPermission) :

     foreach($rolePermissions as $key=>$rolePermission) :  

         if($allPermission->ID==$rolePermission[$key]->permID) {  ?>

          <div class="perms">
            <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" id="<?php echo $allPermission->ID; ?>"  value="<?php print $allPermission->ID; ?>"  checked><?php print $allPermission->permName; ?></option></div>
         <?php } 
        endforeach;
     endforeach;  ?>
```

in normal php you can do this:

```
<?php 
$array=array ( 0 => 
   array ( 0 => array( roleID => 3, permID => 2 ), 
           1 => array ( roleID => 3 ,permID => 3 ),
           2 => array ( roleID => 2 ,permID => 4 ),
           3 => array ( roleID => 2 ,permID=> 5 ) ) );


    foreach($array as $allPermission) 

     foreach($array as $key=>$rolePermission)  

         if($allPermission->roleID==$rolePermission[$key]->permID) {  ?>

          <div class="perms">
            <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" id="<?php echo $allPermission->ID; ?>"  value="<?php print $allPermission->ID; ?>"  checked><?php print $allPermission->permName; ?></option></div>
         <?php } 

 ?>
```